# Combination of pair elements within list in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to obtain the combinations of each element in a list within a list. Given this case:

my_list

[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]

The output would be:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | B |
| 1 | C | D |
| 2 | C | E |
| 3 | D | E |
| 4 | F | G |
| 5 | F | H |
| 6 | F | I |
| 7 | G | H |
| 8 | G | I |
| 9 | H | I |

Or it could also be a new list instead of a DataFrame:

my_new_list

[['A','B'], ['C','D'], ['C','E'],['D','E'], ['F','G'],['F','H'],['F','I'],['G','H'],['G','I'],['H','I']]

Comment: can you post what have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. You have to flatten the result of combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations
x = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
y = [list(combinations(xx, 2)) for xx in x]
z = [list(item) for subl in y for item in subl]

z

[['A', 'B'],
 ['C', 'D'],
 ['C', 'E'],
 ['D', 'E'],
 ['F', 'G'],
 ['F', 'H'],
 ['F', 'I'],
 ['G', 'H'],
 ['G', 'I'],
 ['H', 'I']]
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Create combination by [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with flatten values in list comprehension:

```
from  itertools import combinations

L = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
data = [list(j) for i in L for j in combinations(i, 2)]
print (data)
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E'],
 ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'], ['F', 'H'],
 ['F', 'I'], ['G', 'H'], ['G', 'I'], 
 ['H', 'I']]
```

And then pass to `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
   0  1
0  A  B
1  C  D
2  C  E
3  D  E
4  F  G
5  F  H
6  F  I
7  G  H
8  G  I
9  H  I
```

Comment: @David yop, and simlier like accepted answer. `y = [list(combinations(xx, 2)) for xx in x]
z = [list(item) for subl in y for item in subl]` workins same like `data = [list(j) for i in L for j in combinations(i, 2)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_pair( arrs ):
    result = []
    for arr in arrs:
        for i in range(0, len(arr) - 1 ):
            for j in range( i + 1, len(arr) ):
                result.append( [arr[i], arr[j]] )
                
    return result
            
arrs = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']]
print( get_pair(arrs) )
```